# Problem with using open4 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, console, process

I have a script I want to execute with open4.

Here is the file:

## script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
print "Enter your username: "
username = gets
puts "Here is your username: #{username}"
print "Enter your password: "
password = gets
puts "Here is your password: #{password}"
```

Then I fire up IRB and type:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = Open4::popen4("./script")
=> [2649, #<IO:fd 9>, #<IO:fd 11>, #<IO:fd 13>]

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > puts stdout.gets
```

In the last line I thought it should give me "Enter your username: " but it didn't. The screen is empty no matter what I type. I can only terminate it with CTRL+C.

Then i run...

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > puts stdout.gets
```

...again, and this time it gives me "Enter your username: ".

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `stdout.gets` wants to read an entire line including `\n` but the script hasn't printed a newline so far.

So one thing you need to do is replace `print` with `puts`.

Another thing is that the child's output is buffered. You need to set `$stdout.sync = true` at its start or call `$stdout.flush` after each `puts`.